# How to check the state of a semaphore

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, semaphore

I want to check the state of a `Semaphore` to see if it is signalled or not (so if t is signalled, I can release it). How can I do this?

**EDIT1:**

I have two threads, one would wait on semaphore and the other should release a `Semaphore`. The problem is that the second thread may call `Release()` several times when the first thread is not waiting on it. So the second thread should detect that if it calls `Release()` it generate any error or not (it generate an error if you try to release a semaphore if nobody waiting on it). How can I do this? I know that I can use a flag to do this, but it is ugly. Is there any better way?

Comment: How do you define "signalled" for a semaphore? In the general case N out of a maximum M threads have entered it. Is it signaled?

Comment: Release frees up a slot, it doesn't require a thread to be in wait mode. If it's released when there's no one blocked it just means the next caller will fall straight through without blocking. The other thread should only call release when it's needs to release. It shouldn't just call release repeatedly, otherwise nothing will ever be throttled.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can check to see if a `Semaphore` is signaled by calling `WaitOne` and passing a timeout value of 0 as a parameter. This will cause `WaitOne` to return immediately with a true or false value indicating whether the semaphore was signaled. This, of course, could change the state of the semaphore which makes it cumbersome to use.

Another reason why this trick will not help you is because a semaphore is said to be signaled when at least one count is available. It sounds like you want to know when the semaphore has all counts available. The `Semaphore` class does not have that exact ability. You can use the return value from `Release` to infer what the count is, but that causes the semaphore to change its state and, of course, it will still throw an exception if the semaphore already had all counts available prior to making the call.

What we need is a semaphore with a release operation that does not throw. This is not terribly difficult. The `TryRelease` method below will return true if a count became available or false if the semaphore was already at the `maximumCount`. Either way it will never throw an exception.

```
public class Semaphore
{
    private int count = 0;
    private int limit = 0;
    private object locker = new object();

    public Semaphore(int initialCount, int maximumCount)
    {
        count = initialCount;
        limit = maximumCount;
    }

    public void Wait()
    {
        lock (locker)
        {
            while (count == 0) 
            {
                Monitor.Wait(locker);
            }
            count--;
        }
    }

    public bool TryRelease()
    {
        lock (locker)
        {
            if (count < limit)
            {
                count++;
                Monitor.PulseAll(locker);
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 13):

Looks like you need an other synchronization object because [Semaphore](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.semaphore.aspx) does not provide such functionality to check whether it is signalled or not in specific moment of time.

Semaphore allows automatic triggering of code which awaiting for signalled state using `WaitOne()/Release()` methods for instance.

You can take a look at the new `.NET 4` class [SemaphoreSlim](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.semaphoreslim.aspx) which exposes [CurrentCount](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.semaphoreslim.currentcount.aspx) property perhaps you can leverage it.

> **CurrentCount**
>   Gets the number of threads that will be allowed to enter
>   the SemaphoreSlim.

**EDIT:** Updated due to updated question

As a quick solution you can wrap `semaphore.Release()` by try/catch and handle `SemaphoreFullException` , does it work as you expected?

Using `SemaphoreSlim` you can check CurrentCount in such way:

```
 int maxCount = 5;
 SemaphoreSlim slim = new SemaphoreSlim(5, maxCount);            

 if (slim.CurrentCount == maxCount)
 {
    // generate error
 }
 else
 {
   slim.Release();
 }
```

Answer (score 4):

The way to implement semaphore using signalling is as follows. It doesn't make sense to be able to query the state outside of this, as it wouldn't be threadsafe.

Create an instance with `maxThreads` slots, initially all available:

```
var threadLimit = new Semaphore(maxThreads, maxThreads);
```

Use the following to wait (block) for a spare slot (in case `maxThreads` have already been taken):

```
threadLimit.WaitOne();
```

Use the following to release a slot:

```
threadLimit.Release(1);
```

There's a full example [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.semaphore.aspx).

Comment: Indeed, look at the list of Semaphore functions in the [Win32 API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686360(VS.85).aspx): you can create, open or release and that's it. (A kernel driver can get this information – this is how Process Explorer does it – but that's beyond the scope of the .NET question.)

Answer (score -3):

Knowing when all counts are available in a semaphore is useful. I have used the following logic/solution. I am sharing here because I haven't seen any other solutions addressing this.

```
//List to add a variable number of handles
private List<WaitHandle> waitHandles;

//Using a mutex to make sure that only one thread/process enters this section
using (new Mutex(....))
{
    waitHandles = new List<WaitHandle>();
    int x = [Maximum number of slots available in the semaphore];

    //In this for loop we spin a thread per each slot of the semaphore
    //The idea is to consume all the slots in this process 
    //not allowing anything else to enter the code protected by the semaphore
    for (int i = 0; i < x; i++)
    {
        Thread t = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(TWorker));
        ManualResetEvent mre = new ManualResetEvent(false);
        waitHandles.Add(mre);
        t.Start(mre);
    }

    WaitHandle.WaitAll(waitHandles.ToArray());

    [... do stuff here, all semaphore slots are blocked now ...]

    //Release all slots
    semaphore.Release(x);
}

private void TWorker(object sObject)
{
    ManualResetEvent mre = (ManualResetEvent)sObject;
    //This is an static Semaphore declared and instantiated somewhere else
    semaphore.WaitOne();
    mre.Set();
}
```